# Widget for all projects in TFS 2015 on-premise

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have TFS 2015, Version-14 On-Premise - I have many projects and each project has dashboard widgets indicating burndown etc.

e.g. there are 2 projects published at:

- http://tfs.mycompany.com/tfs/DefaultCollection//_dashboards
- http://tfs.mycompany.com/tfs/DefaultCollection//_dashboards

I would like to know how I can publish one of those widgets for each of the projects on the TFS root: http://tfs.mycompany.com/tfs/

Does anyone know of a configuration option for this?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do this.